# Extract a string that is located above and nearest to the matching pattern in a multiline output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, raid

Below is the HP **ssacli** command to see configured hardware RAID details:

```
ssacli ctrl slot=0 show config
```

and its output is as below:

```
HPE Smart Array P408i-a SR Gen10 in Slot 0 (Embedded)



   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK



   Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 0, OK


   Port Name: 1I (Mixed)

   Port Name: 2I (Mixed)

   Array A (Solid State SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (447.10 GB, RAID 1, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS SSD, 480 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS SSD, 480 GB, OK)

   SEP (Vendor ID HPE, Model Smart Adapter) 379  (Port: Unknown)
```

I have to figure out the ***Array*** name in order to delete it by searching for the matching disk info which I get as input from the user. For example, if the disk input is ***1I:1:1*** then I have to search for this string in the output of the above command. Since this disk is available and matching, I have to extract the Array name (here it is '**A**') and once I get this Array parameter then I can go ahead delete this existing RAID configuration.

```
ssacli ctrl slot=0 show config | grep -B 4 '1I:1:1' | grep Array | awk '{print $2}'
```

The problem with the above command is,

- value 4 in the **grep -B** cannot be always constant as the matching disk may come first, second or third or so on under an Array in the output.
- there may be multiple RAID array configurations available in the output, so there may be Array **A**, **B**, **C** etc., I have to find and retrieve the nearest "**Array**" string that matches my input disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following perl oneliner reads the file line by line, recording the last array until it meets the line with the physical drive '1I:1:1':

```
ssacli ctrl slot=0 show config | perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ /Array (.)/) { $array = $1; } elsif ($_ =~ /physicaldrive 1I:1:1/) { print $array; exit; }'
```

Comment: Got from other forum as: `awk -v disk='1I:1:1' '/^[[:space:]]*Array/ {array=$2} $0 ~ disk {print array; exit}'`